# ¿Cómo puedo leer un fichero y hacer un proceso linea a linea?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estoy estancado, estoy tratando de pasar linea a linea los valores de un fichero que estoy leyendo.

Exactamente lo que necesito es:

- leer el fichero
- recoger la primera linea y hacer un proceso con selenium.
- recoger la segunda y mismo proceso y así todo el rato.

así leo el fichero:

```
with open('fichero.txt', 'r') as objeto:
try:
    listado = objeto.readlines()
```

luego abro el selenium, pero a la hora de pasar el parametro no le paso 1 linea, le paso todo el fichero y da error, como puedo sacarlo linea a linea?

Answer (score 1):

El metodo `readlines()` que estas utilizando lee todo el contenido del archivo de una vez, el método que tienes que utilizar es el `readline()` que lo hace linea a linea.

Quedaría de esta manera

```
with open('fichero.txt', 'r') as file:
    line = file.readline()
    while line:
        ... hacer algo con line...
        line = file.readline()
```

Pero la forma aconsejada es utilizar el iterator de esta manera

```
with open('fichero.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        ... hacer algo con line...
```

Answer (score 0):

[`readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=textiowrapper#io.IOBase.readlines) es un método que te va a retornar una lista dónde cada elemento es una de la líneas del archivo leído, luego, es sencillo iterar sobre ésta para leer cada una de la líneas:

```
lineas = objeto.readlines()
for linea in lineas:
    print(linea)
```

Cuando usas [`readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=textiowrapper#io.IOBase.readlines) hay que considerar siempre el tamaño del archivo, y por que no, si vas a leerlo completo o solo unas pocas líneas, en cuyo caso sin duda es más eficiente la respuesta de Jeroni.